# CSS that let's override itself

Tags: css, sass

Is it possible to create a style that let's override himself if there is any other value for it without using !important?
I can't use !important since it will break the animations.

```
.p-20{
  padding: 20px;
}

.panel{
  .heading{
    //this would be the default value and would let himself be override
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="panel">
   <div class="heading p-20">
      My padding is 10px instead of 20px...
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Here the class weight does matter, in order to get your `p-20` working add it under heading inside `panel` and it shall work, or the other way around take `heading` out from panel and place it above `p-20`

Comment: @JoykalInfotech I know that would work but this is a project with thousands of lines of scss I can't let it stay out of order... the purpose of the question is to find out if it is possible to have something like "declare this style as default".
If there isn't I can always do 
```CSS
.heading{
   padding:10px;
   &-large{padding:20px;}
}
```

Comment: There are basically 2 ways, _specificity_ and _!important_, and if they are equal, the last rule in CSS will apply.

Comment: @LGSon Okay that is the answer I was looking for :P i thought there could be an "opposite" to !important. Thank you for the help! :D

Comment: You might want to explain what you mean with _"I can't use `!important` since it will break the animations."_ That part might be easy to solve, and if, you could use `!important` for the rest. Still, `!important` should only be used as a last resort.

Comment: @LGSon I know ```!important``` is always my last resource, I wrote it in the description of the problem otherwise everyone would comment "just use ```!important```" since it is everyone answer in all related questions, that's why I created my own question for this. However I wish there would be a ```!default``` for style like there is for scss variables..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new style and give your style the same specificity and apply it after the one you want to override.

```
<div class="panel">
   <div class="heading p-20 new-class">
      My padding is 10px instead of 20px...
   </div>
</div>
```

css

```
.panel{
  .heading{
    padding: 10px;
  }
  .new-class{
    padding: 20px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know that would work but this is a project with thousands of lines of scss I can't let it stay out of order... the purpose of the question is to find out if it is possible to have something like "declare this style as default".
If there isn't I can always do. Thank you anyway :)
```CSS
.heading{
   padding:10px;
   &-large{padding:20px;}
}
```

Comment: The only way I know is by the specificity. I may not be understanding your exact situation but I have been in your shoes before :) so if I was you, I would create 2 classes like `heading-default` and `heading` and use the specificity+order  to override the styling of the elements that need a different styling.

Comment: I am going to create a heading small, medium and large for my problem. So I would say you questions is right, I am going to mark it as the answer. Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. below is the kinda the answer I as looking for, take a look, thank you so much for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

In the comments @LGSon answered my question with:
 "There are basically 2 ways, `specificity` and `!important`, and if they are equal, the last rule in CSS will apply".
Which means there is anyway to declare a style as default.
Like he said it must be done with `specificity` or `!important`, however `!important` should always be a last resource.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a job for CSS variables where you don't have to care about specificity:

```css
.p-20 {
  --p: 20px;
  padding:20px; /*we keep this for the element without variable*/
}

.panel .heading {
  padding: var(--p, 10px); /* 10px will be the default value if --p is not set*/
  background:red;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="heading">
    My padding is 10px
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel">
  <div class="heading p-20">
    My padding is 20px
  </div>
</div>

<div class="panel">
  <div class="p-20">
    My padding is 20px
  </div>
</div>
```